# How to remove slick slide on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I'm using the awesome [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slide on a project.

The problem is: I have a carousel with 5 divs inside. 4 images and a video.

On mobile (< 768px) I want the slider to show only the images, not the video.
I tried to hide the video div by css but that's not working.

Any ideas on how to do this? Anyone had this need before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the «Filtering» demo at the [Slick's documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Let's use it to solve the issue.

1. Set breakpoints that you need, using the `responsive` option.
2. Catch the `breakpoint` event and read the `activeBreakpoint` property of the carousel. Notabene: when the screen width is greater than the last of the breakpoints, this property returns `null`.
3. Call [`slickFilter` and `slickUnfilter` methods](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/#methods):

   > **slickFilter**
   > Argument `filter`: selector or function
   > Filters slides using [jQuery `.filter` syntax](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

   > **slickUnfilter**
   > Removes applied filter
4. Beware of an infinite loop: these methods cause a re-initialization of the slider, during which the `breakpoint` event again occurs (unless the breakpoint is `null`).
5. Call these methods during initialization too. Don’t forget to define the `init` handler before the initialization.

Check the result: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/NaGGzv
Slides with the `.hide-on-mobile` class become hidden when the screen width is `700px` or less.

```js
var breakpointMobile = 700,
    isChanging = false,
    isFiltered = false;
$('#breakpointMobile').text( breakpointMobile );

$('#myCarousel').on('init breakpoint', function(event, slick){  /** 2. and 5. **/
  if ( ! isChanging ) {                                         /** 4. **/
    $('#breakpointValue').text( String(slick.activeBreakpoint) );
    isChanging = true;
    if ( slick.activeBreakpoint && slick.activeBreakpoint <= breakpointMobile) {
      if ( ! isFiltered ) {
        slick.slickFilter(':not(.hide-on-mobile)');             /** 3. **/
        isFiltered = true;
      }
    } else {
      if ( isFiltered ) {
        slick.slickUnfilter();
        isFiltered = false;
      }
    }
    isChanging = false;
  }
}).slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true,
  responsive: [                                                 /** 1. **/
    { breakpoint: 500 },
    { breakpoint: 700 },
    { breakpoint: 900 }
  ]
});
```

```css
body {                                                          /** Decorations **/
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.my-carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-carousel .slick-next {
  right: 15px;
}
.my-carousel .slick-prev {
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h3>Slides 2, 3 and 5 become hidden when the screen width is&nbsp;<span id="breakpointMobile"></span>px or&nbsp;less</h3>
<p>Active breakpoint is <b id="breakpointValue"></b>. Try to resize the workspace.</p>

<div id="myCarousel" class="my-carousel">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="hide-on-mobile">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="hide-on-mobile">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c33/f66/?text=4" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="hide-on-mobile">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/099/3cc/?text=5" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/f93/fc6/?text=6" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.0/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Slick has the method [slickRemove](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (you have to scroll down a bit):

> Remove slide by index. If removeBefore is set true, remove slide preceding index, or the first slide if no index is specified. If removeBefore is set to false, remove the slide following index, or the last slide if no index is set.

I would just call this method and remove the slide with the video if your current screen size is lower than 768px.

Answer (score 1):

You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:

```
settings: "unslick"
```

instead of a settings object

To remove slick slider on mobile view add above code snippet to responsive breakpoint like this

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: "unslick"
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```