# Remove slick.js slide on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I am trying to remove a slide in my slick carousel when it is on mobile/tablet.

Here is the basic version of the HTML that I have;

```
<div class="wrapper hero-slider" id="myCarousel">
   <div class="hero__item hero__item-home hide-on-mobile">
      <img src="image" alt="" class="hero__bottle hero__bottle- 
      showcase">
      <img src="image" 
      alt="" class="hero__bottle hero__bottle-showcase">
      <img src="image" alt="" class="hero__bottle hero__bottle- 
      showcase">
   </div>
   <div class="hero__item hero__item-home">
      .....
   </div>
   <div class="hero__item hero__item-home">
      .....
   </div>
   <div class="hero__item hero__item-home">
      .....
   </div>
</div>
```

I found this and am trying to get it working with my code, here is the script that I am using to hide the slide.

```
 var breakpointMobile = 700,
    isChanging = false,
    isFiltered = false;
$('#breakpointMobile').text( breakpointMobile );

$('#myCarousel').on('init breakpoint', function(event, slick){  /** 2. and 5. **/
    if ( ! isChanging ) {                                         /** 4. **/
        $('#breakpointValue').text( String(slick.activeBreakpoint) );
        isChanging = true;
    if ( slick.activeBreakpoint && slick.activeBreakpoint <= breakpointMobile) {
        if ( ! isFiltered ) {
            slick.slickFilter(':not(.hide-on-mobile)');             /** 3. **/
            isFiltered = true;
        }
    } else {
        if ( isFiltered ) {
            slick.slickUnfilter();
            isFiltered = false;
        }
    }
        isChanging = false;
    }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hero-slider').slick({
            autoplay: false,
            arrows: false,
            responsive: [
                { breakpoint: 500 },
                { breakpoint: 700 },
                { breakpoint: 900 }
              ]
        });
```

The code doesn't break anything it seems to just not work. I did realise that I had some class names wrong (might still have) which I thought was the problem but still no luck.

This is the answer that I was following;

[How to remove slick slide on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661011/how-to-remove-slick-slide-on-mobile)

The only thing that I can see differently is how slick is called;

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hero-slider').slick({
        });
```

I feel like this must be an issue but I don't see why it would be.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Zack

Comment: which language are you using on server side?

Answer (score 0):

You'll first have to determine is a user is browsing the website on a mobile device. You can achieve this by using the `Navigator` header passed by the browser. You can do this by:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

and then use `if(isMobile.any())` to find out if the user is on mobile.

To make use of this with your slider, you can use:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       if(!isMobile.any()) {
             $('.hero-slider').slick({ /* slider code here */ });
       }
    });
```

Comment: Ahh I have used this before. I might have worded my question wrong but it would be nice for it to happen when you are just resizing the browser and not actually on mobile. I took a break there for a bit and will have another look at this now and hope I can get it to work. Thanks for the reply :)